# Console.log is not logging strings, only objects

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, console.log

When developing WebExtension in Firefox not all of the "console.log" statements are working.
In the below example only the last console.log execution shows the object reference in the console. all the previous ones are not working.

```
console.log('TEST');
let divs = content.querySelectorAll('.myclass'); // content is a div
for(let div of divs){
    console.log(div.id);
    console.log("bla", div.id);
    console.log(div);
}
```

Comment: We can't see your HTML.  Is there an `id` present?

Comment: Yes, there is an id.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that *duplicates the problem*. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions you almost always need to include your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML, and often webpage HTML/scripts. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't my code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **`JSON.stringify()`** to see the actual string

```
for(let div of divs){
    console.log(div.id);
    console.log("bla", div.id);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(div));
}
```

Comment: Maybe I was not specific enough. This last console.log you've changed was working properly. All the previous ones are not logging anything.

Comment: apply the same for others

Answer (score 0):

I went to **about:config** page and changed some of the settings searching for 'log' string (log levels and extensions.logging.enabled boolean). After restarting the browser the logging was working. I was sure that it was thanks to the **extensions.logging.enabled** setting.

I tried to backtrack and find which setting changes it, but after reverting all the settings and restarting the browser again it was still working.

It turns out that restarting the browser helped, although maybe switching these settings made it work.
So the question can be closed.